# Async method failure in custom OwinMiddleware

Tags: c#, .net, async-await, owin

I have an issue in the custom OwinMiddleware class when I want to send an email whenever some kind of exception occurs on the server.

Basically, this is my OwinMiddleware implementation:

```
public class ErrorNotificationMiddleware : OwinMiddleware
{
    {...}
    public override async Task Invoke(IOwinContext context)
    {
        await this.Next.Invoke(context);
        {...}
        //WORKS
        await Task.Run(() => errorNotificationService.SendMailAsync(errorMessageParams));

        //DOESN'T WORK
        //await errorNotificationService.SendMailAsync(errorMessageParams); 
        
        }
    }
}
```

A method which doesn't work causes a following exception:

> Exception: (System.Net.Mail.SmtpException) Failure sending mail.
>
> Inner Exception: (System.InvalidOperationException) An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle. If this exception occurred while executing a Page, ensure that the Page is marked <%@ Page Async="true" %>. This exception may also indicate an attempt to call an "async void" method, which is generally unsupported within ASP.NET request processing. Instead, the asynchronous method should return a Task, and the caller should await it.

I suppose this is caused because OwinMiddleware (async handler?) will complete request before server sends an email. Taken that into account, .Net detects incomplete asynchronous work and raises exception above.

Since I'm not sure whether I'm right or wrong, may someone confirm me (or explain why) that the working method is perfectly fine to use in this kind of scenario?

Thanks!

Comment: Does `SendMailAsync` just call `SmtpClient.SendMailAsync`? Are you *sure* you're not calling that code from a synchronous method?

Comment: @StephenCleary I suppose that `Invoke` method shouldn't be called from a synchronous method if .Net Owin implementation works asynchronously.   Custom middleware is registered in the Owin middleware pipeline using `app.Use(typeof(ErrorNotificationMiddleware), applicationSettings, errorNotificationServiceFactory);`, where  `app` is `IAppBuilder`. Also, dependencies are injected via DI container (that shouldn't be relevant).

Comment: @StephenCleary in addition we tried directly instantiate `SmtpClient` in the middleware and send an email to bypass few asynchronous calls which we have inside `errorNotificationService.SendMailAsync` method, unfortunately it didn't work as well. One more thing, other async calls (inside service method), such as getting file from LFS works perfectly fine.

Comment: Why are you executing the action inside a `Task.Run`? Why dont you just call and await `errorNotificationService.SendMailAsync` directly?

Comment: @peco as I wrote in the question, what you proposed simply doesn't work and I really don't know why. Because of that I've made temp fix with `Task.Run` which I want to avoid as soon as possible.